# How can I get data from ObservedObject with onReceive in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

In my SwiftUI app, I need to get data from ObservedObject each time the value change. I understood that we could do that with .onReceive? I don't understand well the documentation of Apple about it. I don't know how I can do this.

My code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Compass: View {
  
  @StateObject var location = LocationManager()
  @State private var angle: CGFloat = 0
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image("arrow")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .modifier(RotationEffect(angle: -CGFloat(self.angle.degreesToRadians)))
        .onReceive(location, perform: {
          withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
            self.angle = self.location.heading
          }
        })
      
      Text(String(self.location.heading.degreesToRadians))
        .font(.system(size: 20))
        .fontWeight(.light)
        .padding(.top, 15)
    }
  }
}

struct RotationEffect: GeometryEffect {
  var angle: CGFloat

  var animatableData: CGFloat {
    get { angle }
    set { angle = newValue }
  }

  func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
    return ProjectionTransform(
      CGAffineTransform(translationX: -150, y: -150)
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle))
        .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 150, y: 150))
    )
  }
}
```

In my LocationManager class, I have a heading Published variable, this is the variable I want check.

I need to get data each time the value of heading change to create an animation when my arrow move. For some raisons I need to use CGAffineTransform.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First in your view you need to request the HeadingProvider to start updating heading. You need to listen to objectWillChange notification, the closure has one argument which is the new value that is being set on ObservableObject.

I have changed your Compass a bit:

```
struct Compass: View {

  @StateObject var headingProvider = HeadingProvider()
  @State private var angle: CGFloat = 0

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image("arrow")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .modifier(RotationEffect(angle: angle))
        .onReceive(self.headingProvider.objectWillChange) { newHeading in
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                self.angle = newHeading
            }
        }

      Text(String("\(angle)"))
        .font(.system(size: 20))
        .fontWeight(.light)
        .padding(.top, 15)
    }   .onAppear(perform: {
            self.headingProvider.updateHeading()
        })
  }
}
```

I have written an example HeadingProvider:

```
public class HeadingProvider: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    public let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<CGFloat,Never>()
    
    public private(set) var heading: CGFloat = 0 {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    
    public override init(){
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    public func updateHeading() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
}

extension HeadingProvider: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.heading = CGFloat(newHeading.trueHeading)
        }
    }
}
```

Remember you need to handle asking for permission to read user's location and you need to call stopUpdatingHeading() at some point.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I understand better now. But I have this message : Cannot convert value of type '(Double) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_) -> Void' I need to add something else?

Answer (score 28):

You can consider using @Published in your ObservableObject. Then your onreceive can get a call by using location.$heading.

For observable object it can be

```
class LocationManager: ObservableObject {
@Published var heading:Angle = Angle(degrees: 20)
}
```

For the receive you can use

```
struct Compass: View {

  @ObservedObject var location: LocationManager = LocationManager()
  @State private var angle: Angle = Angle(degrees:0)

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image("arrow")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .modifier(RotationEffect(angle: angle))
        .onReceive(location.$heading, perform: { heading in
          withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
            self.angle = heading
          }
        })
  }
}
}
```

The above is useful if you want to perform additional functions on object changes. In many cases you can directly use the location.heading as your state changer. And then give it an animation below it. So

```
            .modifier(RotationEffect(angle: location.heading))
            .animation(.easeInOut)
```

Comment: I found this answer a little bit easier to follow. Thank you! (I think this should be the accepted answer)

Comment: Thank you! I believe this was the solution to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874566/how-can-i-get-multiple-timers-to-appropriately-animate-a-shape-in-swiftui/. I used onReceive with @Published to have a running timer continue to publish state changes to my View.

Answer (score 10):

### iOS 14+

Starting from iOS 14 we can now use the `onChange` modifier that performs an action every time a value is *changed*:

Here is an example:

```
struct Compass: View {
    @StateObject var location = LocationManager()
    @State private var angle: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ...
        }
        .onChange(of: location.heading) { heading in
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                self.angle = heading
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @LuLuGaGa suggests but it's a bit of a kludge. objectWillChange is defined as an `ObservableObjectPublisher` and while defining it as a `PassthroughSubject<CGFloat,Never>` is going to work today there is no guarantee that it will work in the future.

An object is not restricted to having a single publisher so you can define a second or a third for other purposes than SwiftUI. e.g.:

```swift
class Observable<T>: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let publisher = PassthroughSubject<T, Never>()
    var value: T {
        willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
        didSet { publisher.send(value) }
    }

    init(_ initValue: T) { self.value = initValue }
}
```

Subclassing ObservableObject will correctly define objectWillChange for you so you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: No - objectWillChange has it's type defined by an associated type, so what @LuLuGaGa suggested is fine: `var objectWillChange: Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher`

Comment: Apple say you can re-define objectWillChange to be whatever kind of Publisher you like. WWDC2020 Data essentials in SwiftUI